# How To implement angular-gridster inside an bootsrap element

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, gridster

I am trying to make tiles which will dynamically created based on what response it gets from http request service.

my html page is look like this

```
    <div class="container-fluid" >
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 backlog well" style="margin-left:160px">
    <div class="subjectCenter"><h2>Backlog<i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right"></i></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="spacefortask">
    <addtask></addtask>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 backlog well">
            <div class="subjectCenter"><h2>In Progress</h2></div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 backlog well">
            <div class="subjectCenter"><h2>Done</h2>


        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

and my Angular js files are

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.filters','gridster']);
```

and

```
myApp.component('addtask', {
templateUrl: '/src/views/index.html',
```

});

and index.html page is

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myNokiaController">
        <div ng-repeat="task in myWelcome" class="well">
<div gridster>
    <ul>
    <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in standardItems">
        <div>
    <h1>{{task.taskData}}</h1>
    <h2>{{task.member}}</h2>
        <h3>{{task.time}}</h3>
            </div>
    </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Assume that i am getting the data in myWelcome from http response and i has set the standardItems as

```
    $scope.standardItems = [ { sizeX: 1, sizeY: 1, row: 1, col: 1 }];
```

For every entry in myWelocome i want create one tile so that i have only given one entry in standardItems.
Enough coding i am explaining what i want to do 
So now i am able to create tiles but they are not draggable and they are static so i don't know why it is happening .
And it would be better if anyone suggest me how can i make those items draggable so that it can move to another bootstrap columns (like in first html example )